# Rcpp Parallel is not recognised

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to connect the `RcppParallel` R package. I have tried using both R versions `3.4.4` and `3.5` and I always receive the same package recognition issue.

I have copied the examples demonstrated at the [official Parallel website](https://rcppcore.github.io/RcppParallel/) but still, the package is not working and I can't figure out why. All Rcpp functions are working but not the above package. As I'm using developer based established examples by a letter I can't understand what is wrong.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the code you tried and the error message you got, and also and system info (your current version of RcppParallel and Rcpp, your OS, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your quick  responce. Rcpp and RcppParallel are the latest ones, 0.12.16 & 4.4.0 respecitvely. For character limitations I can't add the entirety of the code but its exactly as suggested on the webside I have provided for the parallel for example. // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <RcppParallel.h>
using namespace RcppParallel; ....//                             [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix parallelMatrixSqrt(NumericMatrix x) ... return output; } If you look in the parallelFor section its all explicitely written there.

Comment: The initial part of error is : c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/library/RCPPPA~1/include" -I"C:/Users/gt42862/Desktop" -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c gt.cpp -o gt.o
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/include/R.h:91:0,
from C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:52,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:38, from C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27, from gt.cpp:40

Comment: @georget It would make your question clearer if you add the info your provided in the comments into your question. Instead of "initial part of error" you want to include the error message(s) itself.

Comment: @georget You can /edit/ your question to include further information like the code in use and the error message you received.

Comment: It's a series of error messages that are similar to the above. It ends with "Error in sourceCpp("C:/Users/gt42862/Desktop/gt.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.". I really can't make any sense of them and I apologize but I can't really add the entirety of it as I'm restricted by character limits.

Comment: Copy it to whatever online document such as google doc and give the link to it.

Comment: This is a google doc drive. It shows my cpp file code, R command and finally error. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oEsfSHPm47vVeRghTEw5JIV3jwyorVmdbBFd51q9fmE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the first error message

> error: 'NumericMatrix' does not name a type

You either have to use full names (`Rcpp::NumericMatrix` etc.) or add

```
using namespace Rcpp;
```

to your sources.

Comment: Thank you for your response Ralf. Indeed you are right, my mistake was assuming that RcppParallel already contained the Rcpp language and it would have recognized those structures. It appears its merely an extension of Rcpp and everything must be declare at the start like you suggested.